# Preview not working in CDE plugin + pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am using pentaho, and to generate reports in it, I am using CDE plug in, I have followed the given instructions and have installed it correctly but the problem is, CDE will create the reports as desired, works efficiently in every functionality but only the PREVIEW is not working.

When I try to preview It gives a plain white blank sheet with no elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you using? First thing, is to try this with Firefox and with Firebug installed. Then check the javascript console to see if there are any errors.

Secondly how did you install CDE?  Did you use the ctools-installer.sh script? If not try re-installing with the script, something could have gone wrong.

Finally how is your BI Server setup? Over SSL by any chance?  How is your SSL conf setup?  I've seen problems in the past with specific SSL setups and it may need a little tweaking.